# How to update a column in a table using a window function

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, window-functions

I have a table in MariaDB with different nodes, each node can have multiple hardware components, and I want to count how many hardware components each node has and store it in a column.

I have therefore created an empty column called "HW_Count". I can do this calculation through the following SELECT statement.

```
SELECT NodeID,COUNT(NodeId) OVER (PARTITION BY NodeId) FROM Hardware AS HW_Count
```

This returns a list of the following kind

```
 NodeID    HWCount
   1         33
   1         33
  ...        ...
   2         11
   2         11
  ...        ...
```

Now I want to UPDATE the empty column in the table called Hardware with tihs information, but I am not sure how I can write the correct UPDATE statement. I want to do something along the lines

```
UPDATE Hardware   
SET HW_count = 
COUNT(NodeId) OVER (PARTITION BY NodeId)
```

But it returns

```
"SQL ERROR (4015): Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause".
```

What is the correct way to update my column?

Thanks!

Comment: In the update statement `SET HW_count = ...`, `HW_count` is one of your `Hardware` table column?

Comment: "I have therefore created an empty column called "HW_Count" " Yes, it's the empty column.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer

```
UPDATE Hardware, (SELECT NodeID,COUNT(NodeID) AS `HW_Count`  FROM 
Hardware GROUP BY NodeID) AS dummyTable
SET Hardware.hw_count = Dummytable.Hw_count
WHERE Hardware.NodeID= dummytable.NodeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
UPDATE H1
SET HW_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) HW_count FROM Hardware WHERE NodeID = H1.NodeID GROUP BY NodeID)
FROM Hardware H1
    INNER JOIN Hardware H2 ON H1.NodeID=H2.NodeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
UPDATE Hardware h JOIN
       (SELECT NodeID, COUNT(NodeID) AS new_hw_count
        FROM Hardware
        GROUP BY NodeID
       ) hh
       ON hh.NodeID = h.NodeID
    SET h.hw_count = h.new_hw_count;
```